# How to rename a file in the 14 hive - edited-

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature-receiver, layouts

<strike>I need to rename the user.aspx file in the 14 hive layouts directory in a feature event receiver.  Is this possible ...if so...how?</strike>

OK - Bad idea....This is what i want to do: I have a custom solution where i use a custom master with default content in ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar".  I want this nav bar to be ALWAYS used.  However there are some pages like user.aspx in the LAYOUTS that have their own asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar".  Is there a way to do this?  I.e. force it to use the default content regardless.

TIA

Comment: Depending on your individual other pages, you could just put PlaceHolderLeftNavBar into the hidden zone on the masterpage, and create a new LeftBar zone with a different name for your stuff...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it, you will break your farm. Also, you'll leave it completely unsupported and the next service pack or cumulative update will probably just replace it.

What is it you need to do? There'll be a better, supported method for what you want to do without renaming out-of-the-box system files. Edit your question and provide some more information, I'll be certain there's a method to do what you want without renaming anything.